# Is there any site you can find out about the 'bonus features' of credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, virtual-credit-card, united-states

I'm doing fairly well financially, and pay my credit cards off monthly, so to me they are less useful for financing and more useful as a matter of convenience. As such, I'd like to know more about the convenience angle, which often aren't disclosed as thoroughly as interest rates and rewards programs.

I'm looking for a place to find out more about these features, like

- Which credit cards offer the "virtual credit card" numbers you can use online only with one vendor?
- Which credit cards offer the contactless payment chips?
- Which credit cards offer custom photo ons the front?
- What set of warranty/car-rental-insurance/other guarantees (which I'll probably never use, except maybe the car rental insurance once) are provided?

Answer (score 3):

[Billshrink](http://www.billshrink.com/) offers some pretty neat analysis tools to help you pick a credit card. They focus more on rewards than the features you mention but it might be worth a look.

If you use [Mint](http://www.mint.com/), they offer a similar service, too. If you're not already using Mint, though, I'd look at Billshrink as Mint requires some extensive setup.

**MOD EDIT**  Looks like billshrink.com is shut down.  From their site:

> Dear BillShrink customer,
>
> As you may have heard, BillShrink.com was shut down on July 31, 2013.
>   While we’re sad to say goodbye, we hope we’ve been able to help you be
>   better informed and save some money along the way! The good news is
>   that much of the innovative award-winning BillShrink technology will
>   still be available via our StatementRewards platform (made available
>   to customers by our partnering financial institutions). Moreover, we
>   expect to re-launch a new money-saving service in the future. To see
>   more of what we’re up to, visit Truaxis.com.
>
> We have deleted your personal information as of July 31. We will
>   retain your email address only to announce a preview of the new tool.
>   If you do not want us to retain your email address, you can opt out in
>   the form below. This opt out feature will be available until September
>   31, 2013. If you have already opted out previously, you do not need to
>   opt out again. If you have any further questions, contact us at
>   info@billshrink.com.
>
> Thanks, The BillShrink/Truaxis Team